# How to Open .pdf on a new Tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, url.action

**The Objective:**

I have to print a PDF on a new tab after some tasks have finished correctly.

Steps: I want to execute a method that should go to the server, take the PDF and open it on a new Tab, I was trying with these but is not working:

**Controller**: Export

```
 public ActionResult PrintPdf()
    {
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename= " + MyClassPdfWriter.GetFileName);
        return File(MyClassPdfWriter.GetMemoryStream, "application/pdf");
    }
```

**View**:

```
function TasksSucced(){
      $.get('@Url.Action("PrintPdf", "Export", "new {target = _blank}")');
}
```

Comment: maybe it works but.. that's a little bit dirty.. jeje I'm gonna take a look if there's a better choice, if not I will use for sure your option :D

Comment: yes actually it is a dirty hack. :D Let me also know if you find anything better. :)

Comment: Raman Ty!! I have found it! :)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Solved! That works for me

```
 window.open('/Export/PrintPdf');
```

Comment: The popup blocker is preventing the pdf from downloading in chrome, is there a way to circunvent it? (telling user to allow pop up for this page is beyond their comprehension :/

Comment: Does not work for `base64` encoded files. At least in Chrome.

Comment: @cpacheco you can circumvent the popup blocker by only opening the tab in response to a user action. In other words, have them click a button to open it. So have a button that directly calls window.open().

Answer (score 13):

There several ways to download or view the PDF.

- View

You can set the **content-type** as **application/pdf** in the response header just like `Content-Type: application/pdf`

And in order to open it to new tab in javascript, please add this code.

```
window.open("Here Download PDF url", '_blank');
```

- Download

You need to set the **content-type** as **application/octet-stream** in the response header just like `application/octet-stream`.

And add **download** HTML5 attribute to **a** tag or just **target="_blank"**.

```
<a href="PDF URL" download="pdf">Download</a>
<a href="PDF URL" target="_blank">Download</a>
```

So you can use PDF.js or 3rd library to view the PDF in iFrame or inline page.

Answer (score 4):

```
$("a[target!='_blank'][href$='.pdf']").attr("target", "_blank");
```

Comment: Exaclty what I needed :-)
Thx

Comment: @Mepps Great! Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 4):

If anyone is having a similar problem, none of the above solutions worked for me in Google Chrome (they did work in Firefox)

This code worked in all major browsers:

```
var a = document.createElement('A');
var filePath = 'https://pathtopdf.com/file.pdf';
a.href = filePath;
a.download = filePath.substr(filePath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
document.body.appendChild(a);
a.click();
document.body.removeChild(a);
```

Comment: Does not work for `base64` encoded files. At least in Chrome.

Comment: That downloads the file instead of opening it in a new tab as per question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following solution

```
   jQuery('<form target="_blank" action="' + URL + '" method="get"></form>').appendTo('body').submit().remove();
```

where URL is the pdf url...

Comment: Does not work for base64 encoded files. At least in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [jQuery.deffered](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.deferred/). I prepared sample function for you. It will process getPdf call, and then will resolve promise. Hope this helps

```
function getPDF() {
    return '';
}

getPdf()
  .then(function(response) {
    console.log('response here' + response);
    window.open(response);
  }).fail(function(){
      console.error('failed reposne');
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const openPDF = (link: string) => {
    window.open(link, '_blank');
  };
```

Just use this simple and easy method

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Since `window.open` will not work properly because of browser's policy, you can do it next way.

If you have file URL, you can first fetch it, then convert `response.body` to uint8array, then create blob and open blob in browser. PDF in this case will be opened in a new tab.

```
const res = await fetch(url)
const uint8arr = new Uint8Array(await new Response(res.body).arrayBuffer())

const link = document.createElement('a')
const blob = new Blob([uint8arr], { type: 'application/pdf' })

link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)
link.setAttribute('download', 'file.pdf')

document.body.appendChild(link)

link.click()
```

Answer (score -1):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/72527783

It's work me.

My sample code

```
    var order_id = $(this).data('order_id');

    var url = 'pdf url';

    var data      = {
        order_id
    };

    var myHeaders = new Headers();
    myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    var urlencoded = new URLSearchParams();
    urlencoded.append("param", JSON.stringify(data));

    var requestOptions = {
        method  : 'POST',
        headers : myHeaders,
        body    : urlencoded,
        redirect: 'follow'
    };

    fetch(url, requestOptions)
    .then((response) => response.blob())
    .then((blob) => {
        const _url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        window.open(_url, '_blank');
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });
```