# Open PDF in a new tab after it downloads

Tags: javascript

I want to open a pdf from an url in a new tab, so i used the usual window.open(url, '_blank'), but when i do, it open a new tab and download the PDF.
How to force the navigator to display the PDF (in a new tab) instead of downloading ?

Comment: Have you tried adding http header `content-disposition: inline`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition

Comment: We can't add a header with window.open

Comment: do it from server side

Comment: @Boursomaster ugh, he means for the mime type *.pdf

Comment: We don't have access to the server side

Comment: Make a page and iframe it if you really want to control what the user does with their own browser.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Opening a new tab to read a PDF file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16925481/opening-a-new-tab-to-read-a-pdf-file)

Comment: That's what i do with window.open(url,  '_blank'); 
The problem is that the url download the pdf

Answer (score 0):

The solution i found is to download the PDF, convert it a as a blob, then convert that blob into a new URL, then open it with window.open.

```
      fetch(url, {/* YOUR CUSTOM HEADER*/ })
    .then((response) => response.blob())
    .then((blob) => {
      const _url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      window.open(_url, '_blank');
    }).catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
```