# Not able to preview pdf files in new tab

Tags: javascript, reactjs, base64

I have a functionality of uploading files. Before uploading, user can see "how many and which files they selected for upload", so user can see preview before uploading.

Whenver user selecting any file, I am converting selected files in `base64` format.
Now lets suppose, I selected a PDF file, it will convert to `base64` and that base64 I am using in `href` of `<a href={base64} target="_blank">{fileName}</a>`.
It will look like this:

[image]

Now, If I click on the `link`. It will open a new tab for preview our PDF file. But I need to refresh the opened tab to preview pdf file. If don't refresh, it will show blank page. If I select `open link in new tab` then I am able to see preview. But I don't know why it is not working when we click on the link.

Comment: this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15944245/how-to-open-pdf-on-a-new-tab#:~:text=And%20in%20order%20to%20open,Download

Comment: @AlaaEddineCherif I tried `window.open` but still I need to refresh the page.

Comment: @AlaaEddineCherif Above link is not helpful for me.